# PublishEngine.IsPublished() so slow

Tags: web8, publishing, templating, tom.net

We recently migrated from Tridion 2011 to SDL WEB 8.5 and suddenly, in one of our environments (staging), an specific page started to take over 2 hours to being published.

This page has a tbb c# which gets information about a lot of components and check if the page which uses each component is published in the current target.

Usually, publishing the page last 10 minutes, but now, is taking too long and we get time out(this is happening only in staging, in dev environment, with the same amount of components, the page gets published good)

Yesterday I did a test, removing this verification, and the page was published in 10 minutes, also I debugged and getting the information if each page is published or not (PublishEngine.IsPublished()) takes over 4 secs.

Just in case, the syntax we are using is: 
`PublishEngine.IsPublished(localPage, pubTarget, true)`

Can I do some index or cleaning to improve the performance ?

thank you !!
Carolina

Answer (score 2):

Are you running the recommended regular database maintenance on your databases? This could indeed help.

https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/maintaining-sdl-tridion-databases

You could also try accessing all `PublishInfo` for a given page using the following to see if the performance improves

```
foreach (PublishInfo info in PublishEngine.GetPublishInfo(page))
{
    info.PublicationTarget.Title; 
}
```

You could also decompile the libraries, and check if there has been any change in the way SDL executes this method that could shed light on the slow down.

Comment: +1 for the database maintenance, -1 for the decompile suggestion

Comment: Hi @chris-morgan, updating the statics and rebuilding the indexes was the solution ... just a quick question, do you know how often should we run these maintenance tasks? We are planing to schedule them in our production environment. Thanks